IntersectionObserver and clip-path not working on iPad or iPhone
I have a header animation using GSAP starting with text and then a video is revealed on scroll using a clip-path to 'zoom' the video in. This is then fully revealed and eventually scrolls off the screen.
There is an IntersectionObserver on the video which plays/pauses it depending on whether 50% of it is visible. The idea behind this is so that the video starts from the beginning once the users scrolls down, and then pauses when off-screen. This works on desktop and on android phones but the IntersectionObserver does not work with the clip-path on iPad or iPhone whether using Safari or Chrome. The IntersectionObserver works when the video scrolls off-screen just not with the clip-path.
Because of the GSAP animation the video is effectively onscreen at the start but hidden with the clip-path which I presume is where the problem lies but, as I said, the IntersectionObserver works on everything else.
Any ideas please as to why iOS won't recognise this or if there are any known issues? I can't find anything.
The code I am using. There are multiple videos further down the page which is why the code is set up like this.
let videoPreloadObserverOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.5 // Trigger when img is 1% visible
  };
  var videoPreloadObserver = new IntersectionObserver(videoPreloadObserverCallback, videoPreloadObserverOptions);
  function videoPreloadObserverCallback(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const video = entry.target.querySelector("video");
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        video.pause();
      }
    });
  };
  document.querySelectorAll(".video-preload").forEach((preload) => {
    if (preload) {
      videoPreloadObserver.observe(preload);
    }
  });

